# Checking if bind() fails

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-errors

Currently, I'm trying to check if the bind() statement fails in my code. From what I know, the way to go about this would be to check this condition:

```
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr)) < 0) 
{
   G4cerr <<  "bind failed: " << strerror(errno) << " " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << G4endl;
   return(-1);
}
```

But I get the following error when I do this:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('__bind<int &, sockaddr *, unsigned long>' and 'int')
```

I can see that '<' is a binary operation, which cannot compare two different data type but can't understand the reason for bind() not returning an integer value.

What am I missing here?

PS. This is a part of a GEANT4 application that someone in my lab wrote.

Comment: You have accidentally run into a naming collision with [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Use ::bind to select the socket function rather than the one in the Standard Library.

Comment: @user4581301 I thought I was using the std::bind without explicitly mentioning it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Shob There is a bind function in the standard library, in the std namespace, which has nothing to do with sockets. Using ::bind selects a function in the global namespace, which is where the socket bind function lives.

Comment: note the `<` and `>` in the error message `__bind<int &, sockaddr *, unsigned long>`. The compiler thinks you are trying to instantiate a `std::bind` object rather than call the `bind` function. This is probably because of a `using namespace std` in the file or a header pulling `std::bind` into the global namespace where it has the same name as the function `bind`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Damn! Thanks. That worked. :)

Comment: @user4581301You got it. Thanks a lot! :)